# How to count number of items in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists. I am creating a function to show a certain slice of that list, and I want it to also tell me the number of rows and columns that have been printed. Here is my code.

```
def explore(dataset,start,end,rows_columns=True):
    opened=open(dataset,encoding="utf8")
    data=list(opened)
    for elements in data[start:end+1]:
        print(elements)
        print('\n')
    if rows_columns==True:
        print('Number of columns = ',len(data[0]),' and number of rows =  ', len(data[start:end+1]))
```

When I tried this out on a data set, I got this.

Input:

```
explore('googleplaystore.csv',0,3)
```

Output

```
App,Category,Rating,Reviews,Size,Installs,Type,Price,Content Rating,Genres,Last Updated,Current Ver,Android Ver



Photo Editor & Candy Camera & Grid & ScrapBook,ART_AND_DESIGN,4.1,159,19M,"10,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art & Design,"January 7, 2018",1.0.0,4.0.3 and up



Coloring book moana,ART_AND_DESIGN,3.9,967,14M,"500,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art & Design;Pretend Play,"January 15, 2018",2.0.0,4.0.3 and up



"U Launcher Lite – FREE Live Cool Themes, Hide Apps",ART_AND_DESIGN,4.7,87510,8.7M,"5,000,000+",Free,0,Everyone,Art & Design,"August 1, 2018",1.2.4,4.0.3 and up



Number of columns =  112   and number of rows =  4
```

So I understand why I get the right number of rows. Its because in the list of lists, each list is counted as one element, for lack of the technical term, but when working out the length of a single list, each term in the list has its characters are counted, rather than the term itself being counted.

I wanted to know if there was any function or way to count the number of items in the list, that would give me the number of columns. Right now I only know of len() which gives me the total number of characters in the list.

EDIT:

It turns out the data was not a list of lists. Using reader() first fixes this problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's a list of lists, it looks like you just have a list of strings. Which would explain the result you are getting.

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data and your expected output ?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps/home, this is where I have taken my data from. The expected output is the one shown above, its just that my column number is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
len(data[0].split(','))
```

split gives us list in return.

Comment: kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps/home is where I got my data from. I've opened the googleplaystore.csv file from there. The .split fixed it, thanks, still learning python so didnt know that existed.

Comment: ok fine, i was not knowing it was tab separated or comma separated, so just asked for sample dataset